# Что из себя представляет мьютекс под капотом?

Tags: linux, c, многопоточность

Test-and-set это инструкция процессора, а сам мьютекс обычная переменная, а функция lock использует под капотом эту инструкцию, правильно понимаю?
Реализация мьютекса в ядре linux?
Много написано, что это примитив синхронизации, для критичных участков памяти, но мне хочется понять, что это обычная реализация в ядре, или еще где то.

Comment: По крайней мере  [musl-libc](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/thread/pthread_mutex_timedlock.c) использует реализацию в ядре (выполняет syscall)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В первом приближении блокировка/разблокировка мьютекса будут выглядеть как-то так (псевдокод):

```
struct mutex {
  atomic int is_locked;
  /* ... */
};

lock(struct mutex *mtx) {
  while(test_and_set(mtx->is_locked, 1)!=0) {
    wait_sleep(mtx);
  }
}

unlock(struct mutex *mtx) {
  is_locked = 0;
  wake(mtx);
}
```

- `test_and_set()` — это [соответствующая инструкция процессора](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set), которая атомарно присваивает переменной новое значение и возвращает старое, например, на x86 это [`XCHG`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xchg).
- `wait_sleep()` — функция, приостанавливающая поток, ожидающий на мьютексе. Под капотом она всегда использует какой-либо системный вызов т.к. засыпание потока с целью дождаться какого-либо события всегда происходит в ядре. Практически<sup>¹</sup> о всех вариантах libpthread для Linux мьютексы реализованы с помощью [`futex()`](https://ru.manpages.org/futex/2).
- `wake()` — функция, пробуждающая хотя бы один процесс, ожидающий на этом мьютексе (если таковой имеется). Она также реализуется средствами ядра.

Так если при входе в `lock()` в `is_locked` будет `0`, но функция просто установит единицу и сразу вернётся. Если же в `is_locked` будет `1`, то `test_and_set()` её не изменит, но отправит процесс в ожидание.

---

#### Распространённые модификации

Производительности ради и не только, обычно в реализации также часто бывают:

- Цикл с попыткой захватить мьютекс с помощью [спин-блокировки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) перед тем как перейти к `wait_sleep()`
- Использование [CAS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC)-инструкций вместо `TAS`
- Проверка, есть ли процессы, ожидающие мьютекс перед вызовом `wake()`

---

> мне хочется понять, что это обычная реализация в ядре, или еще где то.

Основная часть реализации находится в пространстве пользователя (захват блокировки), но она использует и поддержку со стороны ядра (засыпание до освобождения блокировки). При этом обычно реализация старается минимизировать количество переходов в режим ядра т.к. это довольно дорогая операция, но полностью реализовать мьютексы без этого невозможно.

<sup>¹ «Практически» здесь употреблено исключительно из-за того, что в противном случае кто-то обязательно сделать свой вариант libc просто дабы опровергнуть это утверждение.</sup>

Comment: @0andriy, и что именно здесь смущает?